# Переопределение имен утилит из binutils

Tags: c++, cmake, кросс-компиляция

Собственно вот какой вопрос ... Всем известно, что если в скрипте перед командой **./configure** сделать такую объявку:

```
export CC=clang
export CXX=clang++
```

То последующие инструменты сборки постараются вместо компилятора `GCC` использовать `clang`. С этим всем понятно.

Но возникла другая ситуация. Я использую кросс-компиляторы из проекта [mxe.cc](https://mxe.cc) для сборки GUI-библиотеки [nana](http://nanapro.org/en-us/). В `nana` система сборки базируется на `cmake`. У каждого "комплекта" свой `cmake`. И вот смотрите мой скрипт:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

export PATH=/home/majestio/Dev/cross/mxe/usr/bin:$PATH
export TARGET=x86_64-w64-mingw32.shared

export CC=$TAGRET-gcc
export CXX=$TAGRET-g++
export LD=$TAGRET-ld
export DLLTOOL=$TAGRET-dlltool
export DLLWRAP=$TAGRET-dllwrap
export AS=$TAGRET-as
export AR=$TAGRET-ar
export RANLIB=$TAGRET-ranlib
export NM=$TAGRET-nm
export WINDRES=$TAGRET-windres
export PKG_CONFIG=$TAGRET-pkg-config

$TARGET-cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Release" -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS:BOOL=ON
make
```

По сути он запускает `x86_64-w64-mingw32.shared-cmake`. Тот игнорирует все мои переопределения - я пробовал. Он сам находит нужные компиляторы из "своего" комплекта, а вот `dlltool` не находит. Хотя в комплекте он есть, и называется он `x86_64-w64-mingw32.shared-dlltool`.

**Поэтому пару вопросов**

1. Какие из моих переопределений вообще неверные, ну кроме `CC` и `CXX` даже для `./configure`?
2. Как мне приручить `cmake` к нужным мне переопределениям имен утилит из `binutils`?

Comment: Все "переопределения" неверные. И вообще, это не переопределения, а переменные окружения и они могут работать, только если потом где-то их разворачивает. Прибегание к их использованию обычно говорит о том, что вы делаете что-то не так. Если используете кросс-компиляцию, то следует переопределить тулчейн для cmake.

Comment: Так а как мне заставить `cmake` из тулчейна (я об это написал в вопросе) видеть нужный его `dlltool`?

Comment: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Свою задачу сборки я решил. Хотя остались некоторые вопросы, которые не касаются именно моей задачи. Тем не менее, опишу сделанное - может быть кому-то поможет.

**Касаемо ./configure**

Скрипт `./configure` к `binutils` никакого отношения не имеет. Это файл, генерируемый системой сборки `autotools` (а именно `autoconf`). Достаточно часто `./configure` уже присутствует в архиве с исходниками в готовом виде. И кросс-компиляция настраивается просто указанием необходимых параметров.

**Касаемо cmake и dlltool**

`cmake` о многих инструментах из `binutils` тулчейнов просто не знает. Это же и касается `dlltool` (специфичный инструмент для windows-цели, для генерации библиотеки импорта). О чем "знает" `cmake` - можно посмотреть, набрав:

```
cmake --help-variables | less
```

Как правило, это переменные вида:

```
CMAKE_<LANG>_COMPILER
CMAKE_<LANG>_COMPILER_AR
CMAKE_<LANG>_COMPILER_RANLIB
CMAKE_<LANG>_LINK_EXECUTABLE
CMAKE_AR
...
```

Но про `dlltool` или `windres` - там ничего нет!

Соответственно, в моем случае никакие манипуляции с параметрами `cmake` для кросс-компиляции нужного результата не дали. Пришлось смотреть и редактировать исходние конфигурационные файлы проекта, отвечающие за поиск `dlltool`. В результате получилось следующее.

Мой скрипт сборки приобрел вид:

```
#!/bin/sh

export MXE=/home/majestio/Dev/cross/mxe/usr
export PATH=$MXE/bin:$PATH
export TARGET=i686-w64-mingw32.shared

$TARGET-cmake .. \
 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Release" \
 -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS:BOOL=ON \
 -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$MXE/$TARGET \ 
 -DCMAKE_DLLTOOL=$MXE/bin/$TARGET-dlltool
```

А в конфигурационном файле проекта **shared_libs.cmake** внес правку:

```
-- shared_libs.cmake-old    2020-02-08 07:30:54.000000000 +0300
+++ shared_libs.cmake   2022-08-20 11:22:33.835154661 +0300
@@ -10,7 +10,7 @@
             set(DLLTOOL OFF)
         else()
             # mingw: If dlltool is found the def and lib file will be created
-            find_program (DLLTOOL dlltool)
+            find_program (DLLTOOL ${CMAKE_DLLTOOL})
             if(NOT DLLTOOL)
                 message(WARNING "dlltool not found. Skipping import library generation.")
             endif()
```

Это все и решило мою проблему. Библиотеки импорта стали генерироваться.

Надеюсь кому-то поможет.